# Python: Error with code when using IDLE and Xcode on MAC

Tags: python, xcode, macos, python-idle

I have no idea how to run it or create it as an application. The application is saved to my desktop as lucky Number.py.

I am new to Python am a MAC User I have IDLE and Xcode installed but on executing my application I got an error message.

Code starts with

```
from random import randint
def pick_lucky Number():
  maxm=53
  maxj=6
  m=maxm
# create all numbers from 0 to m
  r=range(m+1)
# start with an empty result
  v=[]
  for j in range(maxj):
        # get ith number from r...
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Terminal (in your Finder, search for 'Terminal') and navigate to your Desktop where you have 'Number.py'.  To run your program (which has errors - see below), type in the following: python Number.py

Corrected Code below:

```
from random import randint    

def pick_lucky_Number():
    maxm=53
    maxj=6
    m=maxm
    # create all numbers from 0 to m
    r=range(m+1)
    # start with an empty result
    v=[]
    for j in range(maxj):
        # get ith number from r... 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pick_lucky_Number()
```

You want to make sure that:

1. Your function 'pick_lucky Number' is one name (i.e. connected with underscores)
2. Space your code (Python is sensitive to code)
3. The main program is calling your function